# subnetting question

Tags: subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work)

what is the last valid host on the subnetwork 192.168.176.200/30 and how did u get ur answer

Comment: Smells like *homework*!

Comment: @ChrisS: Ya' think? How did u get ur answer?

Comment: Kid's these days! What do they teach them in school? Apparently not how to do research. "I asked the internet and they told me."

Answer (score 4):

[How Does Subnetting Work](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work) Take a look at the mentioned post.  It should answer your questions.

For reference though:

```
192.168.176.200/30 - Mask of 252 (Block size of 4 (256-252)) In the four Octet. 
A /30 means 30 network bits are "on" (1's) so:

1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1111.1111 1100 = /30

Looking at the forth octet: 1111 1100 = 252 in Decimal

Your valid subnets increment by the block size... In this case 4

So your valid subnets would then be 192.168.176.0, 192.168.176.4,...192.168.176.252

192.168.176.200 -> 192.168.176.200 to 192.168.176.203 (.204 is the next subnet)
192.168.176.201 -> first valid host
192.168.176.202 -> last valid host
192.168.176.203 -> Broadcast Address
```

However, I HIGHLY suggest reading the "How Does Subnetting Work" post.